# What is the reason for an object not found error when using a batch file to run MS access module?

Tags: vba, ms-access, batch-file

I'm using the following batch file to open my access database and attempt to run a module (macro) from within the database.

Batch file:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Users\%Username%\OneDrive - Colony Brands\Desktop\CID FE v3.1.accdb" /x MasterRun
```

Module (BuildFileAutoRun):

```
Public Sub MasterRun()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAutoBuild", acNormal, "", "", acEdit, acNormal
    
Item:     [Forms]![frmAutoBuild]![cboYear] = "2020"
          [Forms]![frmAutoBuild]![cboBrand] = "Ashro"
          [Forms]![frmAutoBuild]![cboSeason] = "S21"
          
Forms!frmAutoBuild.cmdCreate_Click
End Sub
```

The problem is I keep getting the following error displayed by **Microsoft Access** with a message box:

> **Microsoft Access cannot find the object 'MasterRun.'**
> If 'MasterRun' is a new macro or macro group, make sure you have saved it and that you have typed its name correctly.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: MasterRun is not a macro, it is a VBA procedure. If command line switch expects a macro then build a macro. Macros in Access, unlike Excel, are not VBA code.

Comment: Sorry syntax I get what you mean. What I have written as a VBA procedure I've been calling a macro but Access has it's own "Macro" builder which is what I have my batch file setup to run. Okay so I need to figure out how to run a VBA sub through my batch file instead.

Comment: You can use a **macro** called `AutoExec` to launch your **VBA function**.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. In order to get this to work I just created a macro in Access that then runs the code I want it to run. The bat file now works. I appreciate the help, and I learned something today too :)

Answer (score 1):

The command line switch expects name of a macro object. MasterRun is not a macro - it is a VBA procedure. Macros in Access are not VBA code (macros in Excel are really just VBA procedures). Three types of macros: general, embedded, data. Use the Macro builder button on ribbon Create tab for general macro, embedded macros are within forms and reports, data macros are associated with tables.

Macros can call VBA Function, not Sub, procedures. So either use equivalent macro commands to accomplish opening form and populating controls or build a Function that can be called by macro.

A general macro named AutoExec will execute automatically when database opens - no need to be referenced in switch.

Another option is code behind form set in database Options (or AutoExec macro) to open by default when database opens - use form Open event to run code when form opens.